# jquery color pick on index.html

Tags: jquery, css

i try to add a jquery plugin in my app but not working :|
so in head i have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="./style/colorpicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jqueryColorPicker/colorpicker.js"></script>
```

and somewhere in body:

```
<script>
        $("./images/colorwheel.png").ColorPicker({
            color: '#0000ff',
            onShow: function (colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                return false;
            },
            onHide: function (colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                return false;
            },
            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                $('#footer').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
                $('#header').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

but that wheel didnt appear on my page:| im new in jquery... :(

Comment: your selector `$("./images/colorwheel.png")` is wrong....

Comment: what should i put instead ??:|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You didn't include `jquery` library in the `<head>`.

2.The selector is wrong, for example if you want to attach the color picker to textbox #colorpicker , the code should be:

```
<input type="text" id="colorpicker">    

$("#colorPicker").ColorPicker({ ... });
```

3.Put the code inside $(document).ready ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#colorPicker").ColorPicker({ ... });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector for the color picker $("./images/colorwheel.png") is wrong.

You need to have a html element on which the color picker should work.

You can have something like

```
    <div class="someClass"><div>
```

And then you should initialize the colorpicker over it like this

```
    $(".someClass").ColorPicker({
        color: '#0000ff',
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('#footer').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            $('#header').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an element which will hold your ColorPicker:

```
<input type="text" id="colorPicker">
```

Initialize the ColorPicker on that element:

```
$("#colorPicker").ColorPicker({
...
```

You should also use `ready` to make sure that your element is loaded when executing the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Your code
});
```

And if you have multiple color pickers on your page, you'll have to use classes instead of the id.

Comment: Just put your javascript code where I wrote `//Your code`. The problem without the ready is that the element might not be loaded when you call `ColorPicker` on it.